# New line character representation in Java

Tags: java, regex, string

I have a field in database that looks like this

```
abcd.\nefgh
```

On a Java side, I get it into a variable (message), and need to split that variable on two parts: first and second.

Something like this:

```
message="abcd.\nefgh" ;//This is not what happens ???
first = //Anything before '\n'
second = //Anything after '\n'
```

I tried the following

```
if(message.indexOf('\n')>-1){
  first = message.substring(0, message.indexOf('\n'));
  second = message.substring(message.indexOf('\n')) ;
}
```

However, my code never enters into the body of the if statement.
I checked with debugger, and it reveals that my message variable is indeed

```
abcd.\\nefgh
```

So, I tried it with the use of String.split method,

```
String rabit = "Abcd\\nEfgh" ;
System.out.println("Results \n "+  rabit.split("\n")) ; //1
//and alternative
System.out.println("Results \n "+  rabit.split("\\n")) ; //2
```

However, Here is the problem.  In both, 1 and 2 outputs, I get an array with only one element. - the full message.  The pattern was not found.

So, can anyone help - what is the problem here?  The fact that my variable message comes from database with the \n? Any other suggestions? How can I resolve this ?

Comment: Looks like it has already been answered. Use `\\\\n` in `Split`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If the string contains the literal `\n` then you would need *four* escape characters in the `split` delimiter regex:

```
rabit.split("\\\\n")
```